# Testing a function and assert that it calls another one inside of the same class

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, phpunit

Assuming a class `ApiClient` being tested, how do I assert that `storeToken()` is properly called in `retrieveNewToken()`, my problem is that I can't use `expects()` method since `$this->testedInstance` is not a mock which is set up using :

ApiClient

```
private function retrieveNewToken()
{
        $response = $this->client->post(
            'login',
            [
                'json' => [
                    'username' => $this->apiLogin,
                    'password' => $this->apiPassword,
                ],
            ]
        );
        $statusCode = $response->getStatusCode();
        $responseBody = json_decode($response->getBody());

        if (Response::HTTP_OK === $statusCode) {
            $this->storeToken($responseBody->token);

            return $responseBody->token;
        }

        $exception = sprintf(
            'Error retrieving token : %s',
            $responseBody->message
        );
        $this->logger->error($exception);
        throw new \Exception($exception);
    }

private function storeToken($token)
{
    $tokenCacheItem = $this->memcache->getItem('token');
    $tokenCacheItem->set($token);
    if (!$this->memcache->save($tokenCacheItem)) {
        throw new \Exception('Error saving token');
    }
}
```

Right now my test is :

ApiClientTest

```
public function setUp()
{
    $this->testedInstance = new ApiClient($dependencies);
}

public function tearDown()
{
    $this->testedInstance = null;
}

public function retrieveNewTokenOK(){
    $entityMock = $this->getMockBuilder(ApiClient::class)
        ->setConstructorArgs([
            $dependencies;
        ])
        ->setMethods(['storeToken', 'prepareClient'])
        ->getMock();

    $guzzleClientMock = $this->getMockBuilder(Client::class)
        ->setConstructorArgs([
            [
            'base_uri' => $this->baseUri,
            'proxy' => ''
            ]
        ])->getMock();

    $entityMock->expects($this->once())->method('prepareClient')->willReturn($guzzleClientMock);

    $responseMock = $this->getMockBuilder(Response::class)->setConstructorArgs(['', Response::HTTP_OK])->getMock();
    $responseMock->expects($this->once())->method('getStatusCode')->willReturn(Response::HTTP_OK);
    $responseStreamMock = $this->createMock(StreamInterface::class);
    $jsonDecode = $this->getFunctionMock(ApiClient::class, 'json_decode');
    $jsonDecode->expects($this->any())->with($responseStreamMock)->willReturn((object) ['token' => 'JWTTOKEN']);
    $entityMock->expects($this->once())->method('storeToken')->with('JWTTOKEN');

    $this->invokeMethod($entityMock, 'retrieveNewToken');
}
```

Comment: does `$this->storeToken()` employ a dependency? You could mock it...  And where does `$entityMock` come from?

Comment: @xmike I updated with storeToken() method, yes it uses Memcached, the ApiClient's constructor has a method $this->client = $this->prepareClient($baseUri); I use a random $baseUri somehow Guzzle still instantiates like it isn't mocked and I get a "Could not resolve http://test.com ($baseUri)"

Comment: looks like you could simplify your case by a) creating mocks for memcache and guzzle, and b) having them injected into real `ApiClient`. I mean there seems to be no need to mock `ApiClient`, even partially -- I think no real need to set expectations for  its `storeToken()`, you'd rather want to make sure `memcache` is reached, isn't that so?

Comment: I mocked all of those, it seems even ApiClient needs to be mocked in order to be able to test the call to another another function of the same class. So I removed the new ApiClient() and instead used a mock inside the test, the problem now is using ```$entityMock->expects($this->once())->method('prepareClient')->with($this->baseUri)->willReturn($guzzleClientMock);``` the ApiClient's client attribute is still null resulting in ```Error: Call to a member function post() on null``` which is called in ```retrieveNewToken()```

Comment: "...to be able to test the call to another another function of the same class" -- that's exactly what i suggest not to do. I think the goal can be reached mocking only dependecies, if memcahe's `save()` reached, task is accomplished.

Answer (score 0):

I understand your struggle. I have been there many times and I think I can help you. Usually, when some piece of code is hard to test, it just needs some restructuring into smaller parts. I took the liberty to restructure the code a little bit, to make it more testable. Here you find the result, I will explain it in more detail.

The production code:

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App;

use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class ApiClient
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $apiLogin;
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $apiPassword;
    /**
     * @var Client
     */
    private $client;
    /**
     * @var LoggerInterface
     */
    private $logger;
    /**
     * @var TokenStorage
     */
    private $tokenStorage;

    public function __construct(
        string $apiLogin,
        string $apiPassword,
        Client $client,
        LoggerInterface $logger,
        TokenStorage $tokenStorage
    ) {
        $this->apiLogin = $apiLogin;
        $this->apiPassword = $apiPassword;
        $this->client = $client;
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
    }

    public function retrieveNewToken(): string
    {
        $response = $this->client->post('login', [
            'json' => [
                'username' => $this->apiLogin,
                'password' => $this->apiPassword,
            ]
        ]);

        $body = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents());
        if (Response::HTTP_OK !== $response->getStatusCode()) {
            $errorMessage = sprintf('Error retrieving token: %s', $body->message);
            $this->logger->error($errorMessage);
            throw new \Exception($errorMessage);
        }

        $this->tokenStorage->storeToken($body->token);
        return $body->token;
    }
}
```

And the test class:

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App;

use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response;
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class ApiClientTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * @var ApiClient
     */
    private $apiClient;
    /**
     * @var Client|\PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_MockObject
     */
    private $client;
    /**
     * @var LoggerInterface|\PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_MockObject
     */
    private $logger;
    /**
     * @var TokenStorage|\PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_MockObject
     */
    private $tokenStorage;

    protected function setUp(): void
    {
        $this->client = $this->createMock(Client::class);
        $this->logger = $this->createMock(LoggerInterface::class);
        $this->tokenStorage = $this->createMock(TokenStorage::class);
        $this->apiClient = new ApiClient('test', 'test', $this->client, $this->logger, $this->tokenStorage);
    }

    public function testCanRetrieveNewToken(): void
    {
        $response = new Response(200, [], '{"token":"test-token"}');
        $this->client->expects($this->once())
            ->method('post')
            ->willReturn($response);

        $this->tokenStorage->expects($this->once())
            ->method('storeToken')
            ->with('test-token');

        $token = $this->apiClient->retrieveNewToken();

        self::assertEquals('test-token', $token);
    }

    /**
     * @expectedException \Exception
     * @expectedExceptionMessage Error retrieving token: Something went wrong
     */
    public function testThrowsExceptionOnUnexpectedStatusCode(): void
    {
        $response = new Response(400, [], '{"message":"Something went wrong"}');
        $this->client->expects($this->once())
            ->method('post')
            ->willReturn($response);

        $this->apiClient->retrieveNewToken();
    }
}
```

As you can see, I extracted the token storage logic into it's own class. This is to follow the Single Responsibility Principle, which is about creating small classes that do only thing. This decision also makes the ApiClient more testable as you can now simply assert that when a new token is retrieved the TokenStorage class is called with the correct token. The implementation of the TokenStorage class will also have its own test, where you can mock the Memcache class.

Another point to notice is that I changed the default path of the function from throwing an Exception to returning the new token. This has to do with Clean Code and how people are used to reading code. When reading the `retrieveToken` method for the first time, it will be clear that it will return the new token.

I hope this makes sense.

Cheers!

Comment: Totally agree withe the CleanCode refact but I really don't like the fact that I have to create a TokenStorage class whose only behaviour is to call Memcache behind, its only added value would be handling Memcache's operation errors ?